# Reading and writing CSV files into a data structure suitable for Excel-style column/row manipulations

Tags: php, python, excel, csv, pandas

So I am currently working on a web-application with a few other people for a client, and we've hit a stumbling block. Basically we need to be able to upload a CSV file in a specific layout - and the application will take that CSV file and based on specific columns and their values, it will perform the algorithm and calculations required.

The output would also be a downloadable CSV file. None of us have had experience working with CSV in Python.

The layout of the CSV file is as follows:
ID, Name, Address, Suburb, Postcode, Email, Phone

I need to take the address fields and use that in a calculation to determine how to get to the destination from their specific address. I would also need to print the specific details related to that person as well.

**EDIT**
Okay so basically, the CSV file will contain details about employees and their relevant personal information. What our application does is takes that information, and based on the employees address, will predict the most optimised route for them to get to the destination. 
Basically how the hell do I read CSV files and then write an algorithm based on a certain column/row to perform my calculations required.

Comment: What's your actual question? Do you have any example code or example data that would demonstrate the specific problem you want to solve?

Comment: No sorry I don't have any specific code as of yet since I'm still in the wood-works with the problem.  I'll update the question with some more specific details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a `.csv` is easy with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) standard library module.

A more efficient library that allows for better manipulation of `.csv` files is [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), you should consider playing around with this one first.

For instance, given a csv file:

```
csv = r"""col1,col2,col3,col4
          bar,20150301,homer,53
          foo,20150502,bart,102
          barfoo,20150201,lisa,13
          foobar,20150501,marge,97"""
```

We can operate on it with the `csv` module:

```
import csv # built-in no need to install
from StringIO import StringIO 

with open(StringIO(csv), 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # Do whatever you need
```

And, similarly, with pandas:

```
import pandas as pnd # external, installation required

# returns a dataframe, specify cols, index et cetera 
df = pnd.read_csv(StringIO(csv),
    header=0,
    index_col=["col1", "col3"], 
    usecols=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
    parse_dates=["col2"])

# do dirty things with it.
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me quite a lot. I liked the #dirty things as well. xD

Comment: We need more humor in documentation :). You're welcome Nomm.